# Are events of a general event processor processed in parallel

Tags: qt, events

I currently have attached a signal to a slot of type QueuedConnection and I know with this type the signal is processed by the event handler of the destination object which holds the slot.Now my question is are the events in a general event handler processed in parallel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are processed sequentially